# Is UNIX shell programming interpretation based?

Tags: shell, unix

I just started learning UNIX and out of curiosity, I want to know if UNIX shell scripts compiled or interpreted by the shell? My guess is interpretation. I am not sure though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are 100% interpreted. Pretty much any time you hear the word "script" you can assume that it's interpreted.

Comment: Except when talking about javaSCRIPT ... so, SH/BASH are almost always directly "interpreted", but this can't be extended to "scripting languages" (although I far prefer the term "programming languages"...)

Comment: @pst no that's interpreted too.

Comment: A modern JS engine will "interpret" no more than the JVM after the "parsing" stage. Python can skip this step with PYC files; dynamic lookups do not count as "interpretation".

Comment: @pst seriously? I'm not having this argument. Interpreters can be damn smart, sure. But anything that doesn't require a compilation is by definition an interpreter. How is it that javascript begins running before a page finishes loading? Only an interpreter could do that.

Comment: Just because languages X *requires* compilation upfront says *nothing* about the implementation of language Y. By the previous logic, Scala and Haskell are both *compiled* and *interpreted* languages. Parsing != Interpreting. Have to look deeper into the *implementation* in which, for the case of SH/BASH I concur.

Comment: @pst where are the javascript compilers then? What native or intermediate byte-code does javascript produce?

Comment: SpiderMonkey has [bytecode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/SpiderMonkey/Bytecodes). V8 has native compilation. Both are different JavaScript implementations. "The JavaScript frontend constructs an AST from the source text, *then emits stack-based bytecodes* from that AST as a part of the JSScript data structure." It is about the **implementation**.

Comment: you might also look at Clojure -- it's definitely a compiled language, but with a single-pass compiler which can be invoked as content is streamed in, allowing it to have a REPL running interactively-entered compiled code. :)

Comment: Or ClojureScript -- which is very definitely compiled down to JavaScript, but where that compiler can be invoked incrementally (when whole-program optimization is not in use).

Answer (score 2):

There exist compilers for the shell language, e.g. the proprietary CCsh: http://www.comeaucomputing.com/faqs/ccshfaq.html

The mainstream implementations of the shell do not compile whatsoever.

The shell language is designed with a complete disregard for the possibility of compiling.

Comment: I wonder what such compilers would be doing? running a preprocessor first to sequence the code of all the commands and then compile it into one single stand-alone executable?

Comment: What would it be doing? Normal compiler stuff: parsing the shell syntax to a tree and then emitting some code to do whatever it does. For instance `for x in *.foo ; do ... ; done` might translate to some code which sets up some iteration over file names with a call to `glob`, and then executes a C loop. The `do ...` part is translated into the body for that loop, etc.   At the very least the compiler could get rid of some of the overheads of interpretation, even if it is otherwise not well optimized.

Comment: @Kaz On the other hand, it could just be packaging SH with the script inside a single executable ... ;-) I mostly kid here, and I have no idea what CCsh does and it makes it sound like more than that (although it provides no information on performance cases :-/), but this sort of stuff *is* done in some cases.